# superset dashboards - dynamic updates

Tags: python, oracle, apache-superset

I'm testing Apache superset Dashboards, It s a great tool.

I added an external Database source (Oracle), and I created nice Dashboards very easily.

I would like to see my Dashboards updated regularly and automatically (3 times a day) in superset.

But my Dashboards are not updated.

I mean when a row is inserted into the Oracle Tables, if I refresh the Dashboard, I cannot view the new data in the Dashboard.

What is the best way to do it ?

=> Is there a solution / an option to force the Datasource to be automatically updated regularly ? in a frequency ? What is the parameter / option ?

=> is there a solution to import in batch csv files (for instance in python), then this operation will update the Dashboard ?

=> other way ?

My environment:
Superset is Installed on ubuntu 16.04 and Python 2.7.12.
Oracle is installed on another Linux server.
I connect from  google chrome to Superset.

Comment: I tried to use the command "superset update_datasources_cache" on the ubuntu server side, but even after having restarted superset, my Dashboard is not updated. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I just found the origin of my error... :-)

In fact I added records in the future (tomorow, the day after, ...)...

And My dashboard was only showing all Records to the today date...

I inserted a record before, I refreshed and It appeared.

Thanks to having read me...

Answer (score 0):

You could set the auto-refresh interval for a dashboard if you click on the arrow next to the **Edit dashboard**-button.

Answer (score 0):

Set the cache timeout in preset -

In preset/superset > dataset > edit > setting > cache timeout > set to 10
and then preset/superset > database > edit > advanced > performance > set all three cache timeout to 10.

This refreshed the filters and the chart according to the new data.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).